# What does "叱吒" mean?

Tags: meaning

After some searches here and there, why does "叱吒" translate to "rebuke"? Could it also mean something like "being at the top of [location]"?

Comment: Translation of metaphoric words is difficult. Honestly, Chinese-English dictionaries are only for beginners. Some terms are not very accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The translations on internet are not very accurate. I will give the best translations of 叱咤 and 叱咤风云 below. :P

The word chì zhà can be written as 叱吒 or 叱咤, but not 叱诧 (chà）。

Originally, it means 大声吆喝、呵斥 (shouting loud and powerfully)。It is often used in the idiom 叱咤风云。It means 怒斥之声,令风云失色。形容轰动一时的人物。(Thundering voices out-powered roaring storms. It describes a phenomenal and influential character.)

Comment: What's the difference when it's written as 叱咤 and 叱吒, might I ask? My IME doesn't include 叱吒 at all, even for traditional. Is the 叱吒 spelling accepted in Taiwan, but still less common than 叱咤?

Comment: You can actually use either one as you like. I found both forms used in mainland, HK and Taiwan.

Answer (score 0):

"叱吒" is original describing a sound that somebody yells angrily and loudly.

There are phrases "叱吒风云" / "叱吒樂壇", to translate, I would suggest "to get rocked in sth."